# How do I log SQL statements from JDBC calls without mySQL server running?

Tags: java, logging, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

So, I'm trying to figure out how to log the SQL statements that would be run, without actually having an active mySQL server.

The problem I'm trying to solve is right now we're writing data to both a remote mySQL instance, as well as a local (archive data). We're logging to a local as a backup in case the remote becomes unreachable/goes down/etc.

So, what we'd like to do instead is log the SQL statements locally (we're going through Spring JDBC Template w/variable replacement), so not quite as easy as taking the SQL we piece together ourselves and write it to a file.

I did find [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) which looks great, except we'd still need a local mySQL instance active, even if it's just using the blackhole engine. I did think maybe we could just use the log4jdbc on the remote server, but if the connection goes away, will the JDBCTemplate even try and run the queries on the underlying JDBC driver objects before getting the failure? Most pooling mechanisms will validate the connection before returning it, so it'd still just fail before the query had a chance to run & get logged.

So, who has any bright ideas?

Comment: You should probably stop trying to re-invent database replication. Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html

Comment: We're not after replication. We're trying to get rid of the mysql instance on the local machines which is only used as a backup of archive data in case the main mysql server goes down and we need to scrap the data from the individual servers and combine them on the main mysql server.

Comment: It still sounds like you're trying to re-invent replication. Or backup. Or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark O'Connors solution is probably the best in general, but the way we solved this was to simply write out the data as CSV files formatted to be ready for import via a load data infile statement.

Answer (score 0):

Run the remote MySQL instance with [bin logging enabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto-masterbaseconfig.html).

The [binary logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log.html) can be backed up and if necessary converted into SQL using the [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) command, to later restore a database.

Comment: What happens if the mysql instance goes down? Or a switch breaks in between? Each server needs to log the data locally. Right now that's to a local mysql instance, but we're trying to remove the local mysql server and just simply log the SQL which could then be replayed on the main mysql instance once it comes back up if the need arises.

Comment: According to the documentation "Beginning with MySQL 5.6.2, the binary log is crash-safe. Only complete events or transactions are logged or read back". It really does sound to me that your use-case requires local instances of MySQL running. It was my understanding you wanted a single database instance and record enough information that enables you to rebuild the data later. I therefore would refer you to the PITR doco: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/point-in-time-recovery.html